# How to connect more than one monitor to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Windows 7 laptop which has one HDMI connection. I connect one monitor via HDMI to this laptop no problem. Can I connect more than one monitor to this laptop and achieve HDMI quality even though I have just one HDMI port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMI signals can not be split. Your options are:

1. Check if your laptop has a mini display port, or vga port in addition to the hdmi port
2. Buy a usb video card like [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815290023)

Comment: wrong link, it redirects to another question ?

Comment: I think I have a 'mini display port' but all links when googling seem to point to the Mac computers/laptops. Is this connection hdmi quality ? So does the connection run from hdmi on monitor to mini display port on laptop ?

Comment: Yes, display port and mini display port are digital signals just like hdmi. display port is actually better than hdmi in that it supports higher resolutions. Mac's were the first major adopter of the connector, but many pc's now use it too. You will just need a display port to hdmi cable/adapter like this http://www.amazon.com/Mini-DisplayPort-HDMI-Adapter-Cable/dp/B003OC6LWM

Comment: great, thanks. so plugging this extra monitor into laptop will display  content on laptop monitor, hdmi monitor and 'mini display port' monitor and no extra config of windows is required ?

Comment: Yes, windows supports multiple monitors natively. Just plug the monitor in, and go to the control panel to choose which monitor is on the right and the which is on the left.